# DataRow: Check for empty (Not "null) fields in DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, datarow

Hopefully this is an easy one.  Is there a way to test for an "empty" field using DataRow?  The following work fine for testing against a field with null values, unfortunately, the column I'm dealing with are either populated with data or are just "empty".  Is there an approach in C# I'm missing?  Thanks

```
if (Particle.Tables.Count == 0 || pDr.ItemArray[1].ToString() == "")
tblParticle.Append("No Data");
```

Comment: Duplicated maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326341/c-sharp-datarow-empty-check

Comment: string.IsNullOrEmpty() tests for either null or a zero-length string

Comment: if you ever decide to return or pass in a DataRow utilize teh link that devGabriel posted for the awesome example as well hope all of this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use stirng.isNullorEmpty to check for empty fields. [String.isNullorEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

```
if (Particle.Tables.Count == 0 || string.isNullorEmpty(pDr.ItemArray[1].ToString()))
{
   tblParticle.Append("No Data");
}
```

.

Comment: I would  suggest wrapping the if statement in a code block { } in the event that he may need to do something different later down the road..

Comment: At the moment, although this all helps, it's still not working for me.  No explanation as to why.  I can see the fields are empty in the database that I'm testing against to technically this "should" work?  If I test this and what I had to start with and change the array position to column with known "nulls" it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pDr.ItemArray[1].ToString()))
{
  tblParticle.Append("No Data");
}
else
{
  //else do something else
}
```

checking for NULL will not hurt keep in mind that Null and Empty are two different things

Comment: Didn't you forget the "string." before the IsNullOrEmpty method?

Comment: yes sorry about that.. I was typing faster than  I was thinking.. thanks devGabriel

Answer (score 1):

- See [DataRow.IsNull method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it accepts a column name or index
  and returns whether it is NULL

The following assumes we are talking about a string (VARCHAR/CHAR) column:

- If you don't care if it is null or an empty string, and always want an empty string back, you can use `DataRow["name"].ToString()`
- If you want your string object to become null or empty just like the field value, you can use `DataRow["name"] as string`
- If you want to get an exception in case of NULL, you can use `(string) DataRow["name"]`