# C# datarow value empty check

Tags: c#, excel, datarow

I'm trying to run a datarow from excel and check if cell value is empty.
If it is empty i want to add it to the other table (as below).
otherwise, keep on checking.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    database11DataSet.tblContacts.NewRow();
    foreach (DataRow r in dsContacts.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = database11DataSet.tblContacts.NewRow();

        object[] itemArray = r.ItemArray;
        // this is a "checking" step
        if (itemArray.Length == 0)
        {
            dr[0] = r[0];
            dr[1] = r[1];
            dr[2] = r[2];

            database11DataSet.tblContacts.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# DataRow Empty-check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326341/c-sharp-datarow-empty-check)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DataRow row in table1.Rows)
{
    object[] itemArray = row.ItemArray;
    if (itemArray.Length < 1 || itemArray.All(r => r == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.ToString())))
    {
        table2.ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Can you add some explanation?
I dont understand how to use it. Im quite new to C#